# View State value for the page and controls

Tags: .net

When will be view state value for the page and controls will be saved.I have searched many sites but not getting a clear cut answer.Anyone please clarify

Comment: Look for the `SaveViewState`-method and the `SaveStateComplete`-event in [this lifecycle overview](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC386473.png).  ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview: [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Comment: So any changes to the values in the viewstate should be done before SaveStateComplete incase to preserve after next postback right?